# How to change Yahoo Messenger 10 status? 

Tags: instant-messaging, yahoo-messenger

How do I change the Yahoo Messenger 10 status according to the music that is playing?

I tried all the software I found. Most of them are old and not compatible with Yahoo Messenger 10. And as a music player I'm using AIMP. Could anyone recommend me a status changer software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://statusrevolution.wordpress.com/ is what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you copy the essential information in the post in case the link dies? That willl help the user. And it will give the world copyright free information when you descripbe how to do that (just do not copy from a copyrighted source please).